# Sort unordered list with href javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an unordered list as :

```
<ul id = "mylist">
 <li><a href="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/cse611-3045f.appspot.com/o/test%40gmail.com%2F10-10-2019%2Ftest%40gmail.com-10-10-2019.xlsx?alt=media&amp;token=21f64bfe-c7ce-4155-a24e-6684e784a8fd">10-10-2019</a></li>
 <li><a href="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/cse611-3045f.appspot.com/o/test%40gmail.com%2F11-10-2019%2Ftest%40gmail.com-11-10-2019.xlsx?alt=media&amp;token=36367037-770e-4e99-b405-571c5aa79a64">11-10-2019</a></li>
 <li><a href="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/cse611-3045f.appspot.com/o/test%40gmail.com%2F5-10-2019%2Ftest%40gmail.com-5-10-2019.xlsx?alt=media&amp;token=407ed4f5-b530-4149-99f6-fde685fba34a">5-10-2019</a></li></ul>
```

I want to sort them into

```
<ul>
  <li a href="#">11-10-2019</a></li>
  <li a href="#">10-10-2019</a></li>
  <li a href="#">5-10-2019</a></li>
</ul>

PS : I want the same URL, just using '#' here to avoid work.
```

But the code currently I have written isnt sorting it properly. I guess it's because of the href?

My code:

```
var container = document.getElementById("myList");
var contents = container.querySelectorAll("li");

var list = [];
for(var i=0; i<contents.length; i++){
    list.push(contents[i]);

}

list.sort(function(a, b){
    var aa = parseInt(a.innerHTML);
    var bb = parseInt(b.innerHTML);
    return aa < bb ? -1 : (aa > bb ? 1 : 0);
});

/* list.reverse(); */

for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
    console.log(list[i].innerHTML);
    container.insertBefore(list[i], container.firstChild);
}
```

Comment: These innerHtml values don't look like ints, they look like dates, you should parse as date and not as int

Comment: Are the dates always going to be in the same month? (I assume 10-2019 is a month?)

Comment: start with `var aa = Date.parse(a.innerHTML)` // and hope that format is the same as Date.parse expects ;)

Comment: Which format are your dates in? If it’s d-m-Y, the current accepted answer will give the wrong results (in practice, not just theoretically – for example, my browser parses `5-10-2019` as May 10th, 2019).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use the `textContent` of the `li` s to get the dates and then compare them directly as date objects, assuming the same structure.

```js
var container = document.getElementById("myList");
var contents = Array.from(container.querySelectorAll("li"));

contents = contents.sort(function(a, b){
    var aa = new Date(a.textContent.replace('-','/'));
    var bb = new Date(b.textContent.replace('-','/'));
    console.log(aa,bb);
    return aa < bb ? 1 : (aa > bb ? -1 : 0);
});

console.log(contents.map(x =>x.innerHTML));
while (container.firstChild) {
    container.removeChild(container.firstChild);
}

contents.forEach(content => {
  container.appendChild(content);
});
```

```html
<ul id = "myList">
 <li><a href="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/cse611-3045f.appspot.com/o/test%40gmail.com%2F10-10-2019%2Ftest%40gmail.com-10-10-2019.xlsx?alt=media&amp;token=21f64bfe-c7ce-4155-a24e-6684e784a8fd">10-10-2019</a></li>
 <li><a href="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/cse611-3045f.appspot.com/o/test%40gmail.com%2F11-10-2019%2Ftest%40gmail.com-11-10-2019.xlsx?alt=media&amp;token=36367037-770e-4e99-b405-571c5aa79a64">11-10-2019</a></li>
 <li><a href="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/cse611-3045f.appspot.com/o/test%40gmail.com%2F5-10-2019%2Ftest%40gmail.com-5-10-2019.xlsx?alt=media&amp;token=407ed4f5-b530-4149-99f6-fde685fba34a">5-10-2019</a></li></ul>
```

Comment: why don't you just subtract dates: `bb - aa`?

Comment: that should work too, did not want to modify the OP code wherever not essential

Answer (score 1):

You’re selecting `li` elements. Their `innerHTML` looks like this:

```
'<a href="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/cse611-3045f.appspot.com/o/test%40gmail.com%2F10-10-2019%2Ftest%40gmail.com-10-10-2019.xlsx?alt=media&amp;token=21f64bfe-c7ce-4155-a24e-6684e784a8fd">10-10-2019</a>'
```

Instead of sorting on the `parseInt` of this value, you should be sorting on the `innerHTML` of the `a` elements, and probably doing a more precise job of it than `parseInt`. For example:

```
/// Compares two dates in d-m-Y format.
function compareDates(a, b) {
    var aParts = a.split('-').map(Number);
    var bParts = b.split('-').map(Number);

    return aParts[2] - bParts[2] ||
           aParts[1] - bParts[1] ||
           aParts[0] - bParts[0];
}
```

with

```
list.sort(function(a, b){
    var aDate = a.children[0].innerHTML;
    var bDate = b.children[0].innerHTML;

    return compareDates(aDate, bDate);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here another way to achieve your goal which parses the text as dates, clears the container and then fills it back up with newly created `list items`:

```js
var container = document.getElementById("myList");
var contents = Array.from(container.querySelectorAll("li>a"));

contents.sort(function(a, b){
    var aa = Date.parse(a.textContent);
    var bb = Date.parse(b.textContent);
    return aa < bb ? -1 : (aa > bb ? 1 : 0);
});

/* contents.reverse(); */

//clear the container
container.innerHTML = '';

for(var i=0; i<contents.length; i++){
    listElem = document.createElement('li');
    listElem.appendChild(contents[i]);
    
    container.appendChild(listElem);
}
```

```html
<ul id="myList">
  <li><a href="#">10-10-2019</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">11-10-2019</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">5-10-2019</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to change your code that much :

you only need to make that change :

```
var aa = new Date(a.querySelector('a').innerHTML).getTime();
var bb = new Date(b.querySelector('a').innerHTML).getTime();
```

```js
var container = document.querySelector("#mylist");
var contents = container.querySelectorAll("li");

var list = [...contents];

list.sort(function(a, b){
    var aa = new Date(a.querySelector('a').innerHTML).getTime();
    var bb = new Date(b.querySelector('a').innerHTML).getTime();
    return aa < bb ? -1 : (aa > bb ? 1 : 0);
});

/* list.reverse(); */

for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
    console.log(list[i].innerHTML);
    container.insertBefore(list[i], container.firstChild);
}
```

```html
<ul id = "mylist">
  <li> <a href="#">10-10-2019</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#">11-10-2019</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#">5-10-2019</a></li>
</ul>
```